# Как смонтировать tmpfs поверх system?

Tags: android, mount, tmpfs

Обратил внимание на mount:

```
 ~ # mount | grep tmpfs | awk -F" " '{print $1 $2 $3 $4 $5}'
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs
tmpfs on /system/bin type tmpfs
tmpfs on /system/etc type tmpfs
```

tmpfs умеет монтироваться поверх? Что же, я пробую так:

```
 ~ # mount -t tmpfs -o size=1G tmpfs /
 ~ # mount | grep " / "
/dev/block/mmcblk0p69 on / type ext4 (ro)
tmpfs on / type tmpfs (rw,size=1G)
 ~ # cd ..
 / # touch test.txt
Error: read-only file system
 / # touch /system/bin/custom
# Magisk mount moment...
```

А поддержки overlayfs, mhddfs и даже unionfs и aufs у меня нету. Но странно: в tmpfs в /system/bin я писать могу (да и Magisk же как-то прокидывает туда модули: я примерно понял механизм magisk mount-а), а вот tmpfs over / - ни в какую! Собственно, а как замонтировать tmpfs поверх системной папки, как это делает, судя по всему, Magisk?

Comment: Не очень понял, что вас смущает в первом выводе, о каком «поверх» идёт речь?

Comment: На своём телефоне я подобных монтирований не наблюдаю (хотя у меня тоже Magisk)

Comment: Касательно нескольких монтирований в один каталог в документации написано, что линукс так умеет [«multiple mounts can be stacked on the same mount point»](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mount.2.html), правда, какое конкретно при этом поведение должно быть, я пока не очень понял

Comment: andreymal, о чем вы? tmpfs в /tmp я монтирую через /data/adb/service.d (аналог init.d). А так - ну, если у вас Android ≥9 (т е system-as-root) - то у вас как у меня)

Comment: andreymal, так каталог /system/bin НЕ ПУСТОЙ! А монтировать (по идее) можно только в пустой каталог. А иначе: нужен aufs, unionfs, overlayfs или mhddfs. А тут tmpfs спокойно монтируется куда хочет)